# Json got parsed but the cannot display the data in the UI flutter

Tags: json, flutter, dart, flutter-widget

I was trying to fetch data results from a REST API and then display it in the UI. So everything went well the JSON was parsed well the try and catch method was working fine. But somehow the code was not able to display the parsed results in the UI. Neither gave me an error or exception. I have been struggling to attain the desired result for quite the past few days.

Model Class:

```
import 'dart:convert';

Transaction transactionFromJson(String str) =>
    Transaction.fromJson(json.decode(str));

String transactionToJson(Transaction data) => json.encode(data.toJson());

class Transaction {
  Transaction({
    required this.dataDescription,
    required this.orderStatus,
    required this.statusObjects,
  });

  String dataDescription;
  String orderStatus;
  List<StatusObject> statusObjects;

  factory Transaction.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) => Transaction(
        dataDescription: json["data-description"],
        orderStatus: json["order-status"],
        statusObjects: List<StatusObject>.from(
            json["status-objects"].map((x) => StatusObject.fromJson(x))),
      );

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => {
        "data-description": dataDescription,
        "order-status": orderStatus,
        "status-objects":
            List<dynamic>.from(statusObjects.map((x) => x.toJson())),
      };
}

class StatusObject {
  StatusObject({
    required this.type,
    required this.status,
    required this.date,
    required this.time,
  });

  String type;
  String status;
  DateTime date;
  String time;

  factory StatusObject.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) => StatusObject(
        type: json["type"],
        status: json["status"],
        date: DateTime.parse(json["date"]),
        time: json["time"],
      );

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => {
        "type": type,
        "status": status,
        "date": date.toIso8601String(),
        "time": time,
      };
}

This is how the JSON looks like:

    {
        "data-description": "This api will return an array of objects to be placed in the order status timeline on the second screen",
        "order-status": "Success",
        "status-objects": [
            {
                "type": "Payment",
                "status": "completed",
                "date": "2021-07-02T00:00:00",
                "time": "12:00AM"
            },
            {
                "type": "Units Allocated",
                "status": "by Axis",
                "date": "2021-07-13T00:00:00",
                "time": "12:00AM"
            }
        ]
    }
```

API_Manager where the parsing and fetching took place Service Class

```
class API_Manager {
  static Future<Transaction> getDetails() async {
    var client = http.Client();
    var transactions;
    try {
      var response = await client.get(
          Uri.https("your api url here"));

      if (response.statusCode == 200) {
        var jsonString = response.body;
        var jsonMap = jsonDecode(jsonString);
        transactions = Transaction.fromJson(jsonMap);
      }
    } catch (e) {
      return transactions;
    }
    return transactions;
  }
}
```

The UI component where I wanted to display the parsed JSON:

**Code**

```
FutureBuilder<Transaction>(
                  future: API_Manager.getDetails(),
                  builder: (context, snapshot) {
                    if (snapshot.hasData) {
                      var data = snapshot.data!.statusObjects;
                      return ListView.builder(
                        itemCount: data.length,
                        itemBuilder: (context, index) =>
                            Text('$index : ${data[index].status}'),
                      );
                    }
                    return Text('Something was wrong!');
                  },
                ),
```

The **output** that I am getting is "Something was wrong"

I am quite sure that I have been missing a very small piece of code to make it work. I have been working on this piece of code for quite a few days but am unable to do it. I request you, people, to please help me out in attaining the result or point out the piece of code that I have left out.

Will appreciate it if you could help me in any possible way.

Comment: print out `response.body`. What value you get?

Comment: Yeah I am getting the json output

Comment: what `statusCode` you got?

Comment: Hey!
I have updated the code.
Also, I am quite new to integrating REST APIs in the code.
So I request if you can then please help me code this problem out

@JohnJoe

Comment: The first thing we need to know is whether the `if` block get executed. Please print out the `response.statusCode`. What value you get?

Comment: No the if block did not got executed. Neither I got any output

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/234761/discussion-between-john-joe-and-pratyay-sinha).

Comment: you are missing to select the key `status-objects`, can you provide `Transaction` calss so I can test easily ?

Comment: Please check @YeasinSheikh I have added the Transaction class.

Comment: Also if you want I have also attached the API

Comment: tried this
`Uri.https("https://api.skidfintech.com/accounts/test-data/"));`

Comment: This is not working in my case

Comment: Hey!!
Would appreciate if you could just have a look at this problem that I am facing
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68603763/i-am-trying-to-store-the-authorization-token-fetched-from-the-rest-api-and-then

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this

```
var response = await client
          .get(Uri.https("domain", "accounts/test-data/"));
```

or

```
var response = await http
      .get(Uri.parse("domain/accounts/test-data/"));
```

This one doesn't work maybe because of the main domain part shouldn't use `/`, because it indicates subPath,

```
      var response = await client
          .get(Uri.https("domain/accounts", "test-data/"));
```

Comment: Although I got the response body in a print statement. But I am still struggling to get the response to the UI.
Kindly can you look at the mistake I am running into

Comment: I'm not getting the UI problem, can you share it. 
may be you can try on 'FutureBuilder'
```
 if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.waiting)
         return CircularProgressIndicator();
  if (snapshot.hasData) {
      .........
```
then

Comment: Hey!!
Would appreciate if you could remove the API URL from the solution.

Comment: Hey!!
Would appreciate if you could just have a look at this problem that I am facing
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68603763/i-am-trying-to-store-the-authorization-token-fetched-from-the-rest-api-and-then

Comment: Hey!!
Can you help me solve a problem?
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68863386/display-a-particular-data-from-a-json-response-in-the-ui-using-flutter/68863446#68863446